# Batch file with two lessc commands, only one executes

Tags: node.js, batch-file, less

I have a batch file with two lessc commands. The first one execute, the second does not.

```
lessc --clean-css app.less app.min.css
lessc app.less app.css
```

How can I make both to run.

Running the batch file on Windows 10 with node.js and less installed.

Comment: are you getting an error? what if you swop the commands? have you tried timeout after the first command?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I tried all you said. I get no errors. I solves it a minute ago by adding & after each command to chain them and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: was going to ask now if you used && glad you're sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I just added `&` after each command to chain them and it worked.

Comment: rather use `&&` using `&` only will initiate the second command, even if the first failed, when using `&&` it will not start the second command unless the first command exited with errorlevel 0.